# Python Recursive maze solver never backtracks all the way back

Tags: python, recursion, python-imaging-library

I have a recursive maze solver with one image (PNG, 200x200) I have tried using try/except to print an exception but nothing prints.

Recursive function

```
def solveRecursiveMaze(arr,x,y):
    successful = False
    if (x,y) == getExitPoint():
        successful = True
    elif isValid(arr,x,y):
        arr[x][y] = "V" #set to V to show it's a visited path
        successful = solveRecursiveMaze(arr, x-1, y)    
        if not successful:
            successful = solveRecursiveMaze(arr, x, y+1)
        if not successful:
            successful = solveRecursiveMaze(arr, x+1, y)
        if not successful:
            successful = solveRecursiveMaze(arr, x, y-1)
    if successful:
        arr[x][y] = "P" #Mark as P to show it's a valid pa
    return successful
```

isValid checks to see if the 2D array has a "W" (for White pixel) at the position passed in, and it is within bounds of the array

```
def isValid(arr,x,y):
    if x < len(arr) and y < len(arr) and x >= 0 and y >= 0:
         if arr[x][y] == "W":
             return True
    return False
```

getExitPoint returns an x,y (pixel) of the point that is found for the exit of the maze

```
def getExitPoint():
     x = crop.size[0] - 1
     for y in range(0, crop.size[1]):
         if(crop.getpixel((x,y)) == (255,255,255)):
             return x,y
         if(crop.getpixel((y,x)) == (255,255,255)):
             return y,x
```

this is how I convert my image to a 2D array

```
maze = []
width,height = crop.size
for x in range(0, width):
    mazeX = []
    for y in range(0, height):
        if(crop.getpixel((x,y)) == (0,0,0)):
            mazeX.append("B")
        elif(crop.getpixel((x,y)) == (255,255,255)):
            mazeX.append("W")
    maze.append(mazeX)
```

- What it is supposed to do, is convert the image into a 2D array, which gets traversed recursively (using backtracking) looking for a successful path, then draws a red line over the path.

The script does not work on this image, it stops at pixel X=76, y=153 every time, and i am not sure what to do/what I'm doing wrong

[image: The script does not work on this image]

The borders are 1px and the path is 1px. There are not any errors, stack-traces, exceptions, or anything thrown. The recursion just stops and the program quits. Any Ideas?

Comment: "The recursion just stops *and the program quits*" "it *hangs at* pixel X=76, y=153 every time" These don't seem to be describing the same behaviour.

Comment: sorry, the recursion stops at those pixels, and then the program exits. not sure why I said it hangs. i've edited the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some various problems with your code, but I think what is happening is that you are running over the recursion limit.  Your maze is fairly large and complex.  I needed to use `4000` (For me, `1000` is the default, and `3000` wasn't large enough).

Not sure what image library you're using; I used [PIL.Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html)

Your input image is actually 203x203, and there is a challenge to locate the entrance and exit.  I assumed the entrance is at the top or on the left side, and the exit is on the right side or along the bottom.

[image]

```py
import sys
import argparse
import PIL.Image
import os

colors = {
    'white' : (255, 255, 255),
    'black' : (0, 0, 0),
    'red'   : (128, 0, 0),
    'green' : (0, 255, 0) }


def isValid(image, x, y):
    if x < image.size[0] and y < image.size[1] and x >= 0 and y >= 0:
        if image.getpixel((x, y)) == colors['white']:
            return True
    return False


def getEntryPoint(image):
    # Search along top.
    for x in range(1, image.size[0] - 1):
        if image.getpixel((x, 1)) == colors['white']:
            return x, 1

    # Search along left side.
    for y in range(1, image.size[1] - 1):
        if image.getpixel((1, y)) == colors['white']:
            return 1, y

    # Maze is invalid if there is no entry point.
    raise Exception('No entry point found!')


def getExitPoint(image):
    # Search along bottom.
    for x in range(1, image.size[0] - 1):
        if image.getpixel((x, image.size[1] - 2)) == colors['white']:
            return x, image.size[1] - 2

    # Search along right side.
    for y in range(1, image.size[1] - 1):
        if image.getpixel((image.size[0] - 2, y)) == colors['white']:
            return image.size[0] - 2, y

    # Maze is invalid if there is no exit point.
    raise Exception('No exit point found!')


def solveRecursiveMaze(image, x, y):
    successful = False
    if (x, y) == getExitPoint(image):
        successful = True
    elif isValid(image, x, y):
        # set to show it's a visited path
        image.putpixel((x, y), colors['red'])

        successful = solveRecursiveMaze(image, x-1, y)    
        if not successful:
            successful = solveRecursiveMaze(image, x, y+1)
        if not successful:
            successful = solveRecursiveMaze(image, x+1, y)
        if not successful:
            successful = solveRecursiveMaze(image, x, y-1)

    if successful:
        # Mark to show it's a valid path.
        image.putpixel((x, y), colors['green'])

    return successful


def main(options):
    solved = False

    if options.depth:
        sys.setrecursionlimit(options.depth)

    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open(options.filename)
    except:
        print('ERROR: Could not open %s' % (options.filename))
    else:
        image = image.convert('RGB')

        x, y = getEntryPoint(image)
        print('Entering maze at x = %d, y = %d' % (x, y))
        solved = solveRecursiveMaze(image, x, y)
        if not solved:
            print('No solution exists.')
        else:
            print('Solved maze.')
            basename = os.path.splitext(options.filename)[0]
            image.save(basename + '_solution' + '.png', 'PNG')

    return 0 if solved else 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--d',
        '-depth',
        dest='depth',
        type=int,
        help='Set Python recursion limit with sys.setrecursionlimit()')
    parser.add_argument(
        'filename',
        help='Image containing the maze.')
    options = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit(main(options))
```

Comment: Sorry, I did a green line over the path, and used dark red for what was visited.

Comment: it's so weird that it is working for you. I am also using PIL, and I cut 1 pixel off of each side, and it gets the entry,exit points just fine. Also, I set my recursion limit to 10,000. I will look for what differences we have and go from there! Thank you!

Comment: While I did find some bugs in my code from your revision it still would not complete. I figured out that using 64-Bit python is causing this, as it runs fine in 32-Bit python. My worry is now, If I try to use larger mazes, I will get a stack overflow since the amount of memory the script can use is limited.